# where can I find good Geb tutorials?

Tags: automated-testing, geb

Where can I find tutorials for GeB automation tool? I couldn't find any tutorials online. Currently, I am a manual tester that uses QTP and Load runner. My company wants me to learn Geb as well.

Comment: Have you tried the [GeB mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/geb-user)?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer GeB manual (Book) on its official site : http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/

Here you can find a good presentation : http://www.infoq.com/presentations/geb

Comment: Hey Ravi, This video was very usefull but not enough. can you guide me where I can get step by step tutorials for it .

Comment: Here you can find GeB tutorial : https://www.udemy.com/geb-spock/